# ORA-06550 PL/SQL for trivial anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
-- Created on 1/23/2024 by VIMUKTHIWATHTHEGAMA 
declare 
  -- Local variables here
  i integer;
begin
  -- Test statements here
  
end;
```

I tried the above code and this error was generated:

```
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
```

Comment: The code you've posted does nothing. It's an incomplete stub. It's not complete enough to be expected to work. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/)?

Comment: The [initial explanation of of blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-826B070B-4888-4398-889B-61A3C6B91349) is a little confusing as it just has comments, like your body; but [the block syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D) shows that the [body](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D__CJACHDGG) has to have at least one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous blocks must always have an execution section between the `BEGIN` and `END`, even if you don't want the block to do anything. Below is the simplest possible PL/SQL block:

```
begin
   null;
end;
/
```